# What is the best way to find index of object from array of objects - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing

Hi I'm trying to find index of an object using key name.

This is how i tried to get index:

```js
var Obj = [
  {
    BData: [
      {id: '1', name: 'C'},
      {id: '2', name: 'Java'},
    ]
  },
  {
    CData: [
      {ccode: '010', cname: 'US'}
    ]
  },
  {
    PData: [
      {id: '21', pname: 'pen'}
    ]
  }
];
var index = Obj.findIndex(x => x.CData);
```

with above snippet from out side I am able to get index, but from in actual implementation getting -1, even though key exist also. Data also similar to above only but not getting the reason.

Comment: you could try comparing it with undefined `var index = Obj.findIndex(x => typeof x.CData !== 'undefined');`.In the above case it is difficult to guess why you're getting -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have Array of objects which have indexes like 0, 1, 2.

`x => x.CData` won't return anything.
So you need to find index of 'CData' as key of object inside that array.

```
Obj.findIndex(x => Object.keys(x).indexOf('CData') > -1 )
```

Please try this way.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

findIndex() method returns the index, if the function returns true, currently you are not returning anything. So modify your code like this:
`var index = Obj.findIndex(x => {return x.CData});`